# UITableview has problem reloading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I've kinda finished my application for a school project but have run into a major "bug".
It's a account management application. Picture:

[image]

Here's the problem when i click on the plus sign, i push a nav controller to load another view to handle the adding and deleting of categories. When i add and return back to the view above, it doesn't update. It only updates after i hit the button on the right which is another view used to change some settings, and return back to the page. I did some research on viewWillAppear and such but I'm still confused to why it doesn't work properly.

This problem is also affecting my program when i delete a category, and return back to this view it crashes cos the view has not reloaded successfully. I will get this error when deleting and returning to the view. "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'".

---

[EDIT]

Table View Code:

```
@class LoginViewController;

@implementation CategoryTableViewController
@synthesize categoryTableViewController;
@synthesize categoryArray;
@synthesize accountsTableViewController;
@synthesize editAccountTable;
@synthesize window;

CategoryMgmtTableController *categoryMgmtTableController;
ChangePasswordView *changePasswordView;

- (void) save_Clicked:(id)sender {
/*
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Category Management" 
                                                message:@"Load category management table view"
                                               delegate:self 
                                      cancelButtonTitle: @"OK" 
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
*/
KeyCryptAppAppDelegate *appDelegate = (KeyCryptAppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
categoryMgmtTableController = [[CategoryMgmtTableController alloc]initWithNibName:@"CategoryMgmtTable" bundle:nil]; 
[appDelegate.categoryNavController pushViewController:categoryMgmtTableController animated:YES];



}
- (void) change_Clicked:(id)sender {

 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Change Password" 
 message:@"Change password View"
 delegate:self 
 cancelButtonTitle: @"OK" 
 otherButtonTitles:nil];
 [alert show];
 [alert release];

KeyCryptAppAppDelegate *appDelegate = (KeyCryptAppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
changePasswordView = [[ChangePasswordView alloc]initWithNibName:@"ChangePasswordView" bundle:nil]; 
[appDelegate.categoryNavController pushViewController:changePasswordView animated:YES];


/*
KeyCryptAppAppDelegate *appDelegate = (KeyCryptAppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
categoryMgmtTableController = [[CategoryMgmtTableController alloc]initWithNibName:@"CategoryMgmtTable" bundle:nil]; 
[appDelegate.categoryNavController pushViewController:categoryMgmtTableController animated:YES];
*/


}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Initialization

/*
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
// Override initWithStyle: if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
if ((self = [super initWithStyle:style])) {
}
return self;
}
*/



-(void) initializeCategoryArray {

sqlite3 *db= [KeyCryptAppAppDelegate getNewDBConnection];
KeyCryptAppAppDelegate *appDelegate = (KeyCryptAppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

const char *sql = [[NSString stringWithFormat:(@"Select Category from Categories;")]cString];

const char *cmd = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pragma key = '%@' ", appDelegate.pragmaKey]cString];
sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

sqlite3_exec(db, cmd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
{
    while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        [categoryArray addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)]];

}
else {
    NSAssert1(0,@"Error preparing statement", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
}



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle


- (void)viewDidLoad {

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
[super viewDidLoad];
}



- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Categories",@"Types of Categories");
categoryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[self initializeCategoryArray];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                           initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                           target:self action:@selector(save_Clicked:)] autorelease];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                          initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction
                                          target:self action:@selector(change_Clicked:)] autorelease];

[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
NSLog (@"view did appear");
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
}


- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

NSLog (@"view will disappear");
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}


- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[categoryTableView reloadData];
NSLog (@"view did disappear");
[super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [self.categoryArray count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell...
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
cell.text = [categoryArray objectAtIndex:row];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

return cell;
}


/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
return YES;
}
*/


/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Delete the row from the data source
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
}   
else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
}   
}
*/


/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
}
*/


/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
return YES;
}
*/


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSString *selectedCategory = [categoryArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; 

NSLog (@"AccountsTableView.xib is called.");
if ([categoryArray containsObject: selectedCategory])
{
    if (self.accountsTableViewController == nil)
    {
        AccountsTableViewController *aAccountsView = [[AccountsTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AccountsTableView"bundle:nil];
        self.accountsTableViewController =aAccountsView;
        [aAccountsView release];
    }

    NSInteger row =[indexPath row];
    accountsTableViewController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [categoryArray objectAtIndex:row]];

    // This portion pushes the categoryNavController.
    KeyCryptAppAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [self.accountsTableViewController initWithTextSelected:selectedCategory];
    KeyCryptAppAppDelegate *appDelegate = (KeyCryptAppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.pickedCategory = selectedCategory;
    [delegate.categoryNavController pushViewController:accountsTableViewController animated:YES];

}

 }  



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
// Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
// For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
[accountsTableViewController release];
[super dealloc];
}


@end
```

And the code that i used to delete rows(this is in a totally different tableview):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Delete the row from the data source

    NSString *selectedCategory = [categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [categoryArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];


    [deleteCategoryTable reloadData];

    //NSString *selectedCategory = [categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    sqlite3 *db= [KeyCryptAppAppDelegate getNewDBConnection];
    KeyCryptAppAppDelegate *appDelegate = (KeyCryptAppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    const char *sql = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Delete from Categories where Category = '%@';", selectedCategory]cString];
    const char *cmd = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pragma key = '%@' ", appDelegate.pragmaKey]cString];
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    sqlite3_exec(db, cmd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_exec(db,sql,NULL,NULL,NULL);

    }
    else {
        NSAssert1(0,@"Error preparing statement", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
}



else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
}   
}
```

Comment: You need to give your code for table view.

Comment: after you delete , you need to remove the object from array also.although you deleted one object , your array count still remained 4.hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In the Tableview commitEditingStyle method..you must be removing the object from category array first,& then deleting the row.
Change your code by putting the code for removing the object from array in the last.

ie.
put the following type of code in last
[categoryArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]

Comment: if this do not help you,just put your code for tableView as Ishu suggested.

Comment: hi i've given the code for the table view and the code that is used to delete my category(this is in a different tableview though). thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Just removing items from the array won't update the table. You need to call reloadData to update the tableview or even better, call the methods on the tableview that let you insert or delete rows with animation without reloading the complete table.

```
insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload the table in viewWillappear

by adding this line

```
[yourTable reloadData];
```

because tables delegate function do not get call on reappear the screen.
But they call when you go to next view again thats why after saving you dont get updated info in table but you get after on more navigation because this time reloadData calls in viewWillDisappear.

and for solving the problem for deleting, you need to follow the iphoneDev ans and instruction.

Comment: @ishu, in the code - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
table has been reloaded.since array is not updated after deleting, there is crash.please go through the code before answering

Comment: @Swastik,he did not get updated table when he come to the view so this problem is solve by reloading table in viewWillAppear.So think before comment.I am not suggesting reload data for crash ok.

Comment: @Swastik: ishu is correct,seelani should reload the table in view will appear.As she has mentioned that after adding new category,when the view appears the new category is not shown.So she should reload the table on appearing of view & not on disappearing.

Comment: hey guys i'm really happy that you guys are "fighting" to give me the right answer, but lets say i move all my normal running of methods and preparing of view to viewdidload, and entering [myTable reloadData] in viewwillappear, the problem is not solved and appears worse than before and i have to quit the app before the changes are visible.

Comment: i hate it when i cant figure out whats wrong with my code at 8pm...but have no problem fixing it at 1.30 am in the morning... -_-"
I just have to place this in viewWillAppear
[self initializeAccountsTableArray];
[accountsTableView reloadData];

Comment: also thanks for all the help and attempts at trying to fix my silly reloading issue! MERRY CHRISTMAS GUYS.

Comment: @seelani gud ur problem solved.There is nothing like fighting here.Everbody was just giving their opinion regarding what could be the cause.we are all here to help each other.

Comment: @seelani Swastik is correct,we are also to try learning more and more. MERRY CHRISTMAS GUYS.

Comment: @seelani Yes I too agree with Swastik,& happy that your problem is solved atlast!!Merry Christmas to all :)